# Match each item in Karate

Tags: karate

I would like assert that the price gross is greater than equal to price_net. Can you please tell me how can I achieve this correctly ? This is what I have done atm.

```
Scenario: Testing

* def response =

"""
{
  "prices": [
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
    { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" }
   ]
}

"""

* match each response.prices[*].price_gross == '#? _ >= 0 && _ >= response.prices[*].price_net'
```

I think the '*' inside the assertion statement is the problem. Because when I run this

```
* match response.prices[0].price_gross == '#? _ >= 0 && _ >= response.prices[0].price_net'
```

it works fine. Please suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sample Code:

```
Feature: Validation

  Scenario: Validation

    * def diff =
      """
      function (A, B) {

      var C = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      C.push(parseFloat(A[i]) - parseFloat(B[i]));
      }
      return C;
      }
      """

    * def response =
      """
      {
        "prices": [
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" },
          { "price_net":"10.50", "price_gross":"12.25" }
        ]
      }
      """
    * json temp = response
    * def pgarr = get temp.prices[*].price_gross
    * def pnarr = get temp.prices[*].price_net
    * def sub = diff(pgarr,pnarr)
    * match each sub == '#? _ >= 0'
```

Comment: here is a simpler way: `* def isValid = function(x){ return x.price_gross * 1 > x.price_net * 1 }
* match each response.prices == '#? isValid(_)'`